# Batch File - Read from a text file with spaces

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I wrote a batch file to read a text file located in a specific path. The `for` statement reads from a text file located in a folder. If this same path had spaces the `for` can't read it. Even if I wrap the path in quotes it still can't read it. The path does exist, I checked multiple times, and confirmed that `for` only works with pathnames that contain no spaces.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong, or, is it a limitation of the batch `for` statement?

**Code:**

```
FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%x in (C:\Users\someuser\VirtualBoxLog\log.txt) DO SET read=%%x
```

If this path contained a space, for example `C:\Users\someuser\VirtualBox Log\log.txt` it can't read from the text file, even if I wrap it in quotes and the folder "VirtualBox Log" existed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution for your problem is enclosing the path in quotes:

```
"C:\Users\someuser\VirtualBox Log\log.txt"
```

But now another problem rises: `for` interprets a quotet string as a string, not as a filename.

To work around this, use the `usebackq` keyword:

```
FOR /F "usebackq tokens=* delims=" %%x in ("C:\Users\someuser\VirtualBox Log\log.txt") DO SET read=%%x
```