# read path from a .txt file in a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, filepath

my batch file starts a program and direct it to the location of the data file. i would like that instead of writing the actual path for the data file (shown below), that the batch file would receive it from a .txt file.

my batch file does:

```
set appPath=c:/aplication folder
set dbPath=c:/somewhere/data place/programeDb
```

my .txt file is in a fixed place (c:/aplication folder) and has one line (that can change)

```
c:/somewhere/data place/programeDb
```

thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Batch File - Read from a text file with spaces](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29086006/batch-file-read-from-a-text-file-with-spaces) and other questions found with [\[batch-file\] read text file variable](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bbatch-file%5D+read+text+file+variable).

Answer (score 1):

Command **FOR** can be used to read a line from a text file and assign it to an environment variable.

```
@echo off
for /F "usebackq delims=" %%L in ("Name of text file with path.txt") do set "DataPath=%%L"
set "DataPath=%DataPath:/=\%"
echo Application path is: %DataPath%
```

This batch file replaces also all slashes by backslashes as on Windows the backslash is the directory separator and not the slash as on Unix, Linux, or Mac.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `for /?`
- `set /?`